# Fur mesh not animating with armature

Tags: animation, armature

I'm working in Blender 2.93 as a fairly new user.  I have a wooly mammoth model which I purchased.  It had some poses but not NLA animations so I bought an elephant model that had animations and replaced the armature in the mammoth.
My issue is that the mammoth has two meshes, one for the mammoth and one for the fur.  The mammoth animates fine but the fur does not move.  I parented them both to the armature.  Any ideas on where I should look to resolve this issue?  I selected both the mammoth and fur meshes, then the armature, then Ctrl-P, deform with default weights.  Is this the correct technique?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the file, but if you've done every thing correctly, you may still need to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode

Comment: Since your second mesh (Fur) has no particle system, simplify your file and post only a part of mammoth -leg, head or what ever  (if you dont want to share file you paid for) ... so we can see an issue. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Thanks - I've spent a couple of days trying to upload a portion of the model to blend-exchange but it always gives an error.  I'll try again tomorrow, maybe it's down.

Comment: The model can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpn38i6tpeezdh5/Mammoth_animation_issue.blend?dl=0